# Как правильно извлечь разнотипную информацию из одной базы данных MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После 10ой строки на 11 и далее в поле **MarketName** идет повторение всех записей, **BTC-1ST**, **BTC-2GIVE** и так далее.

Когда необходимо вывести данные для пары BTC-1ST это не сложно. Указываем WHERE MarketName=BTC-1ST

Но вот если я хочу вывести например:

- **BTC-1ST** - последние 5 значение **Volume**
- **BTC-2GIVE** - последние 5 значений **Volume**
- **BTC-ABY** - последние 5 значений **Volume**

И так далее. То в голове ступор и зависание. Если как описано выше представить данные одним запросом нельзя, тогда можно ли сделать это в формате:

- **BTC-1ST**,10,2017-12-14
- **BTC-1ST**,13,2017-12-15
- **BTC-1ST**,12,2017-12-16
- **BTC-2GIVE**,12,2017-12-14
- **BTC-2GIVE**,11,2017-12-15
- **BTC-2GIVE**,12,2017-12-16
- **BTC-ABY**,11,2017-12-14
- **BTC-ABY**,11,2017-12-15
- **BTC-ABY**,13,2017-12-16

и так далее до конца перечислений в столбце **MarketName**. 
То есть нужно как бы перебрать уникальные значения из **MarketName**, для них для каждого вывести по 5 результатов последних, опираясь на обратную сортировку по TimeStamp.

Comment: не [оно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results) (eng) ?

Comment: Насколько я понял логику вопроса - нет, т.к. мне надо получить не три а весь список, который перечисляется у меня в загашнике многократно, а это около 250 пар. И для каждой пары нужно получить например 5 последних значений отсоротированный по таймстапму. (последние 1250 записей образно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по решению [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results) должно работать вот такое решение:

```
SELECT
    MarketName,
    Volume,
    `TimeStamp`
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MarketName,
            Volume,
            `TimeStamp`,
            (@num := if(@group = MarketName, @num + 1, if(@group := parent_id, 1, 1))) row_number
        FROM mytable t
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT
                            @num := 0,
                            @group := NULL) c
        ORDER BY MarketName, `TimeStamp` DESC
    ) AS x
WHERE x.row_number <= 5;
```

crossjoin нужен, [вроде как](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38535249/8737307), потому что

> MySQL не гарантирует порядок вычисления выражений, поэтому этот момент крайне важен, чтобы код выполнялся последовательно.

P.S. возможно немного криво перевел, подправьте кто-нибудь плз.

Comment: MarketName вместо parent_id - работает, запрос выполняется. Сейчас посмотрю что за результат выдает.

Comment: Все отлично работает. Спасибо за потраченное время.